# Create Envelope Issue

Tags: docusignapi

Envelope creation was working well on the sandbox environment.

After I made the integrator key live, and used it with live account, I am getting following error:

**{"Error calling CreateEnvelope: "}**

I am currently use Rest Api of Docusign.
I am able to successfully create an envelope from postman.

But I am unable from my application

Sample Code:

```
ApiClient apiClient = Configuration.Default.ApiClient;
string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + username+ "\", 
   \"Password\":\"" + password+ "\", 
   \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + IntegratorKey + "\"}";
Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);

AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi();
LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();
EnvelopeDefinition def = new EnvelopeDefinition();
def.Status = "sent";
def.EmailBlurb = "Body";
def.EmailSubject = "Subject";
def.TemplateId = “TemplateId”;

def.TemplateRoles = new List<TemplateRole>()
    {
        new TemplateRole {
            Email = "test@test.com",
            Name = "test test",
            RoleName = "all"
        } 
    };

EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].BaseUrl);
envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].AccountId,def);
```

Comment: please provide the rest of the error message. You can edit your question to add the additional information

Comment: I got only  {"Error calling CreateEnvelope: "} this error message.

Comment: Can you enable API logging in your account to see what request is received  by DocuSign and what response it is sending. You can enable API logging by following [Enable API Logging](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging)

Answer (score 0):

If your app was really truly working via the demo environment, then there are only a couple of issues involved in moving to production.

1. Your integration key needs to be promoted to the production platforms.
2. You need a user name (email) and password from a production account.
3. You need to choose the right production platform for your API calls.

### Choosing the right production platform

See the [docs](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#post-go-live). You need to determine *which* production platform the user's account is on. This can be done dynamically or statically.

The name of the platform determines the URL used for API calls.

Comment: Hello, Larry I have manage all above thing in my application.But i got only {"Error calling CreateEnvelope: "} message from Docusign api.

Comment: Hmmm, I think that error is coming from the SDK, not from DocuSign. The SDK is open source. Can you debug it? You can also try a trace tool such as Fiddler or WireShark to see what, if anything, is being sent to DocuSign.